# How can I use regex to get the second of two dates in a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to extract the *last* date only from a string that looks like the following:

Week 1: 03/06/11 - 03/13/11\n

What regex can I use to get '03/13/11'?

Comment: Why did you jump to the conclusion that regex is required?

Comment: Because of the \n on the end, which may or may not be there.  Some of the JS string functions slipped my mind at the time, so I assumed regex would be a good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to match both the first and second date and then reference just the second match:

```
var str = "Week 1: 03/06/11 - 03/13/11\n";
var secondDate;
var matches = str.match(/(\d+\/\d+\/\d+)\s*-\s*(\d+\/\d+\/\d+)/);
if (matches) {
    secondDate = matches[2];
}
```

In answer to your other question, the specific regex to match '03/13/11' is:

```
/\d+\/\d+\/\d+/
```

which means:

```
one or more digits 
followed by a / 
followed by one or more digits 
followed by a slash 
followed by one or more digits.
```

The advantage of using a regex here is that you can more easily build in flexibility for variable spacing, characters in the string after the second date, etc...  For example, this regex works with all of these:

```
Week 1: 03/06/11 - 03/13/11\n
Week 1: 3/06/11 - 3/13/11\n
Week 1: 3/06/2011 - 3/13/2011\n
Week 1: 3/6/11 - 3/13/11\n
Week 1: 03/06/11 - 03/13/11
Week 1: 03/06/11-03/13/11\n
Week - 1: 03/06/11 - 03/13/11\n
Week 1: 03/06/11 - 03/13/11 and Week 2: 03/014/11 - 03/18/11
```

In addition matches[1] is also the first date so you get both dates with the regex too if that's helpful.

The other methods provided using `split` or `indexOf` do not necessarily have the flexibility to automatically work with all these varying formats.

Comment: Although I ended up using indexOf and substr, this info actually answers the question asked (specific to regex).  In fact, I will probably use this elsewhere.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a regex at all.. you can just use regular string functions.
For example:

```
var myStr = 'Week 1: 03/06/11 - 03/13/11';
var arr = myStr.split(' - ');
var secondDate = arr[arr.length-1];
alert(secondDate);
```

Comment: You left off the \n that the OP had on the end of their sample string.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use a regex. `indexOf` and `slice` do the job pretty well here.

```
var date = 'Week 1: 03/06/11 - 03/13/11';
console.log(date.slice(date.indexOf('-') + 1));
```

Comment: I forgot about `indexOf`. This works, along with `substr()` instead of `slice` (because of the \n at the end)

Comment: This assumes a bunch of things.  It assumes that the spacing around the dash is always exact and that there are no characters after the last date.  The sample string in the OP's question showed a \n after the last date so this would include that and any other characters that followed.  The advantage of using a regex is that you can target exactly only the date characters even if stuff around it varies or is inconsistent.

Comment: It's safe to assume a single space between the dash and date in this case.  The \n might be there, or it might not, which is why substr works better than slice.  This is what I ended up using: `date.substr(date.indexOf('-')+2,8)`

Comment: Are each component of the date always exactly two digits?

Answer (score 1):

This regex when applied to your input : `03/06/11 - 03/13/11\n`

```
var myregexp = /-\s*([0-9\/]*)/;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
if (match != null) {
    result = match[1];
}
```

Yields the result of : `03/13/11`

Answer (score 0):

Who needs regex?

```
var str = "Week 1: 03/06/11 - 03/13/11\n";
console.log(str.substr(-9, 8));
// Output: 03/13/11
```